# UITableView - No Items Label - using third cell like Notes App - Crashes when inserting the first record and deleting the last record

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, uitableview

I would like to implement the same behavior as was done in iOS6 with the notes App, perhaps the same is done with iOS7 I can't remember.

To display the message "No Notes" in the third cell, I have done that just fine, however when I add the first record or delete the last record it crashes.

I don't want to use the table header or footer, I would like to do it the same way as done in the Notes app please.

Similar to this question
[UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPath crash when delete last record](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960037/uitableview-deleterowsatindexpath-crash-when-delete-last-record?rq=1)

so the problem is it crashes when inserting the first record or deleting the last record. The error message is the same:-

CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (1) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (3), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (1 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

I understand the problem and why it happens but I have tried too many different things to resolve it but I didn't know how.

Can someone kindly please help me. Thank and much appreciated.

```
- (NSInteger) tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
    {
            if (self.myModel.count == 0)
            {
                return 3;
            }

            return self.myModel.count;
    }


    - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
            UITableViewCell *cell = [self.tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Identifier" forIndexPath:indexPath];

            if (self.allNotes.count == 0)
            {
                cell = [self initilizeNoItemsCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }
            else
            {
                cell = [self initilizeMyObjectCell:cell forIndexPath:indexPath];
            }

            return cell;
    }


    - (void)controllerWillChangeContent:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller
    {   
            [self.tableView beginUpdates];
    }

    - (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
    {
            switch(type)
            {
                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:

                        //crashes here when inserting the first record
                        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                        break;

                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
                        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                        break;

                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                        [self.tableView reloadData];
                        break;

                    case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                        break;
            }
    }



- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableViewObj commitEditingStyle:(UITableViewCellEditingStyle)editingStyle forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
        if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete)
        {       
                //Crashes here also when deleting the last record
                [MyModel deleteObject:[fetchedResultsController objectAtIndexPath:indexPath]];

                NSError *error;
                if (![MyModel save:&error])
                {
                    NSLog(@"Failed to delete - error: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
                }
        }

        else if (editingStyle == UITableViewCellEditingStyleInsert)
        {

        }
}
```

Ho do I get rid of the fake 3 rows before I add a new record?

Update 1:-

**When inserting a second record.**
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  Invalid update: invalid number of rows in section 0.  The number of rows contained in an existing section after the update (2) must be equal to the number of rows contained in that section before the update (1), plus or minus the number of rows inserted or deleted from that section (0 inserted, 0 deleted) and plus or minus the number of rows moved into or out of that section (0 moved in, 0 moved out). with userInfo (null)

**When deleting a record (not the last record)**
CoreData: error: Serious application error.  An exception was caught from the delegate of NSFetchedResultsController during a call to -controllerDidChangeContent:.  attempt to insert row 1 into section 0, but there are only 1 rows in section 0 after the update with userInfo (null)

After getting Paul's answer, its getting me closer. It crashes when I try to add a second record. Also when deleting anything but the last record.

```
- (void)controller:(NSFetchedResultsController *)controller didChangeObject:(id)anObject atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath forChangeType:(NSFetchedResultsChangeType)type newIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)newIndexPath
{
        NSArray *emptyIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                                     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
                                     [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
                                     nil];

        switch(type)
        {
            case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:                              
                if (self.allNotes.count == 1)
                {
                    [tableView beginUpdates];
                    [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:emptyIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                    [tableView endUpdates];
                }            
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:

                if (self.allNotes.count == 1)
                {
                        [tableView beginUpdates];
                        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
                        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:emptyIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                        [tableView endUpdates];
                }
                break;


            case NSFetchedResultsChangeUpdate:
                [self.tableView reloadData];
                break;

            case NSFetchedResultsChangeMove:
                [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
                break;

        }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: possible duplicate of [UITableView deleteRowsAtIndexPath crash when delete last record](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8960037/uitableview-deleterowsatindexpath-crash-when-delete-last-record)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you delete the last row then the expected row count will be 0 (1 row - 1 row deleted = 0), but your `numberOfRowsInSection` will return 3 - because self.myModel.count is now 0.

A similar thing will occur when you insert the first row - 4 is the expected row count (3 + 1), but 1 is the value from `numberOfRowsInSection`.

You need -

```
NSArray *emptyIndexPaths = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:0 inSection:0],
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:1 inSection:0],
                                 [NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:2 inSection:0],
                                 nil];

case NSFetchedResultsChangeInsert:
     [tableView beginUpdates];

     if (self.myModel.count == 1) {    
        [tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:emptyIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];    
     }     
     [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:@[newIndexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     [tableView endUpdates];
  break;

  case NSFetchedResultsChangeDelete:
     [tableView beginUpdates];
     [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:@[indexPath] withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationAutomatic];
     if (self.myModel.count == 0) {
         [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:emptyIndexPaths withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationFade];
     }
     [tableView endUpdates];
  break;
```

Comment: Hi Paul, Thank you very much for responding I really appreciate it. I am aware it is similar to the other question but the answer was not clear. your answer is getting me closer to resolving it. Now when I add the first record it works fine but when I add the second it crashes with the following error:  Updated above.

Comment: Sorry.  My mistake.  I have corrected the code - the delete/insert of the actual affected row was inside the if statement, but it should be outside, so in the event that count wasn't 1 (or 0 for a delete) the insert/delete wasn't processed

Comment: Thanks again, I am trying the changes, there are couple of side effects but I will report back as soon as I know where its heading, I really appreciate it. Thank you.

Comment: Thank you Paul, this made my day, I still have an issue where if I search in the UISearchBar for text that does not exist, it doesn't display the "No results" message but you have resolved my main issue. Thanks, kind regards. I may open another question after I complete my investigation.

Comment: Paul, yes the side effect is defiantly in the scenario if I search for some text within the searchBar looks like I will need handle displaying a label to display "No Results" myself. Would you agree? or something else is happening ? Thanks.

Comment: Other similar questions here on SO seem to support the idea of having a "No Notes" label behind the tableview which you can hide/un hide based on the table content